# Can Mountain Lion OS X run on HP G62 series using VMWare virtualization?

Tags: macos, virtualization, vmware

My laptop specifications are:

1. Intel Core i3 M350 2.27 GHZ
2. 4G RAM DDR2
3. MS Windows 64 bit is installed

I am trying to install OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.

The setups are:

1. [VMware Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) 8 is installed.
2. VMware Unlocker windows version is installed.
3. Open OS X Mountain Lion.vmx

I got this error message "EFI VMware Virstual SCSI hard drive ... unsuccessful." At this point the virtual machine restarts so I'm at a loss as how to continue to run 10.8 on my VMWare software.

Comment: Where did you get OS X Mountain Lion.vmx? Have you checked with VMWare to see if they support OS X as a guest OS on your version and type of VMware engine? Some light searching shows me that [OS X is only supported on VMWare fusion and ESXi 5.x and Fusion 5.x](http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/MacOSX_10_8.html#VMCG) so looking to them for help might also be a dead end.

Comment: Virtualizing OSX is only legal when using OSX Server. Just thought I should mention it...

Comment: @Linuxios Virtualizing OS X client on OS X client has been allowed since 10.7 (a.k.a Lion.)

Answer (score 4):

A more or less official answer from a VMWare support forum moderator from what I can tell is at
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/428763?tstart=825

In short. Windows CANNOT run an OSX guest OS. The OP in the linked thread is even running a Mac under bootcamp, and hangs at Apple logo on boot. *Proper* hardware emulation is the cited cause. There might even be a bit (pun intended) (intentionally) missing from BootCamp drivers to hinder such activity.